# Resizable option is not working in IE 8 but working fine in firefox

Tags: css

I have an option to resize my portlet. For fire fox its working fine but for IE8 its not working.

[image]

CSS Code:

```
.ui-resizable {
position: relative;
}

.ui-resizable-handle {
background: transparent url() no-repeat 50% 50%;
display: none;
font-size: 0.1px;
position: absolute;
 }

  .ui-resizable .ui-resizable-handle {
display: block;
 }

  .js .ui-resizable-disabled .ui-resizable-handle {
display: none;
 }

   .js .ui-resizable-autohide .ui-resizable-handle {
display: none;
  }

   .ui-resizable-n, .ui-resizable-s {
background-image: url(../images/application/handle_horizontal.png);
height: 14px;
left: 0;
right: 0;
   }

   .ui-resizable-n {
cursor: n-resize;
top: 0;
   }

   .ui-resizable-s {
bottom: 0;
cursor: s-resize;
   }

    .ui-resizable-e, .ui-resizable-w {
background-image: url(../images/application/handle_vertical.png);
background-position: center center;
bottom: 0;
top: 0;
width: 14px;
   }

   .ui-resizable-e {
cursor: e-resize;
right: 0;
   }

   .ui-resizable-w {
cursor: w-resize;
left: 0;
   }

   .ui-resizable-ne, .ui-resizable-nw {
height: 14px;
top: 0;
width: 14px;
   }

  .ui-resizable-ne {
background-image: url(../images/application/handle_ne.png);
cursor: ne-resize;
right: 0;
   }

   .ui-resizable-nw {
background-image: url(../images/application/handle_nw.png);
cursor: nw-resize;
left: 0;
    }

    .ui-resizable-se, .ui-resizable-sw {
bottom: 0;
height: 14px;
width: 14px;
    }

   .ui-resizable-se {
background-image: url(../images/application/handle_se.png);
cursor: se-resize;
right: 0;
   }

  .ui-resizable-sw {
background-image: url(../images/application/handle_sw.png);
cursor: sw-resize;
left: 0;
   }
```

My question is, Is there any css based solution to activate the resizable option for IE ?

Comment: You would need to use JavaScript.

Comment: its IE! what do you expect from it? For a completely cross browser application, you should use js as alex said. Look into libraries, like jQurey, which are cross browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because IE doesn't support that css element.

Something you'll learn eventually is that IE doesn't support a lot of useful things. *cough*

My best advice would be to look for a workaround on Google, but I doubt you will find one. I think you would need to use javascript.